# How can I update an entire table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a `Micropost` table with columns `user_id` and `sender_id` (both integers). I've just added the `sender_id` column and by default it's value is nil for existing table rows. As a one time thing I want all of the `user_id` values to be copied and pasted into the `sender_id` column for the rows already existing. some sort of migration required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this from rails console.

```
Micropost.update_all("sender_id = user_id")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have done it inside the migration, but since you already ran it, you can just do it directly in the rails console:

```
Micropost.all.each do |m|
    m.update_attribute :sender_id, m.user_id
end
```

Comment: I keep getting undefined method each for micropost class.

Comment: Oops. Was missing the `.all`

Answer (score 1):

If its a one time thing I suggest you just run a sql command to do this.

```
update micropost set sender_id = user_id;
```

If you have to make it by rails run the following line in console,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "update micropost set sender_id = user_id"
```